# groupby count of values not equal to other col value pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm aiming to pass a groupby count of values but only considering rows where `Item` and `Item 2` are different. The following achieves this but drops rows if no values are different. If there are one or more values that are present but are identical between `Item` and `Item 2` then I'm hoping to return 0.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,4],  
    'Item' : ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','A','B','B','B'],                  
    'Item2' : ['B','A','A','A','B','B','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','B','A','B','A','A'], 
    'Value' : [5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 3, 1, 4, 6, 7, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3],                         
    })

df1 = df[df['Item'] != df['Item2']].groupby(['Time']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Intended Output:

```
   Time  count
0     1      4
1     2      3
2     3      0
3     4      2
```

Edit 2:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','3','4','4','4'],  
    'Item' : ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','A','B','B','B'],                  
    'Item2' : ['B','A','A','A','B','B','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','B','A','B','A','A'], 
    'Value' : [2, 6, 6, 5, 3, 3, 4, 6, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3],                         
    })

df1 = (df.assign(new = df['Item'] != df['Item2'])
   .groupby('Time')['new']
   .mean()
   .reset_index(name='avg') 
   )
```

Intended Output:

```
  Time      avg
0    1      3.0
1    2      5.0
2    3      0.0
3    4      2.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is not filter, bur count values of `True`s per groups by `sum`, here is passed `Series` `df['Time']` to `groupby`:

```
df1 = (df['Item'] != df['Item2']).groupby(df['Time']).sum().reset_index(name='count') 
print (df1)
   Time  count
0     1      4
1     2      3
2     3      0
3     4      2
```

Another similar solution is create new helper column and aggregate it:

```
df1 = (df.assign(new = df['Item'] != df['Item2'])
         .groupby('Time')['new']
         .sum()
         .reset_index(name='count'))
```

EDIT: You can replace non matched values to misisng values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then replace misisng values by `fillna`

```
df1 = (df.assign(new = df['Value'].where(df['Item'] != df['Item2']))
   .groupby('Time')['new']
   .mean()
   .fillna(0)
   .reset_index(name='avg') 
   )
        
print (df1)
  Time  avg
0    1  3.0
1    2  5.0
2    3  0.0
3    4  2.5
```

Alternative is use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by uniqu values of original `Time` column:

```
df1 =  (df[df['Item'] != df['Item2']]
        .groupby(['Time'])['Value']
        .mean()
        .reindex(df['Time'].unique(), fill_value=0)
        .reset_index(name='avg'))
```

Comment: Thanks @jezreal. Makes sense. Just a quick one, if I wanted an average using the same conditions, how would that apply? I've made a quick edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the pivot tables for pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3],  
    'Item' : ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','A'],                  
    'Item2' : ['B','A','A','A','B','B','B','A','A','B','A','B','B','B','A'], 
    'Value' : [5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 3, 1, 4, 6, 7, 4, 5],                         
        })
# this gives you just the ones were there is a differance
df2 = df[df['Item'] != df['Item2']]

# then sum up the numbers for each item
pd.pivot_table(df2,index='Time',aggfunc='count')
```

This gives you the table

```
      Item  Item2  Value
Time                    
1        4      4      4
2        3      3      3
```

Comment: Sorry @Paul Brennan, not entirely the same as my intended output

Comment: change the aggfunc to 'count'

Comment: Yeh, I played around with dropping rows but I need to return a `0` for single values. I could subset first and then do a count on a separate, then re-merge, but this seems a little in-efficient